# UWP TimeTrigger won't fire

Tags: uwp, background-task

I am trying to run a background task every 15 minutes using the TimeTrigger but for some reason it wouldn't fire.  Tried the Lifecycle Events method and it worked.  Checked the task is registered in the power shell.  What else can be wrong?  One thing I found strangely is when I run

```
var allowed = await BackgroundExecutionManager.RequestAccessAsync();
```

I get back BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy instead of

BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity
or
BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity

Is that the problem?  What is BackgroundAccessStatus.AllowedSubjectToSystemPolicy?

Update:

AllowedMayUseActiveRealTimeConnectivity and AllowedWithAlwaysOnRealTimeConnectivity are deprecated.

Reboot made it work, both the desktop and mobile.  Apparently it's easy to crash the background task process.

Also use this to debug on the desktop:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/debug-a-background-task

Comment: have you tried to uninstall and re-deploy the app to see if the problem gets fixed?

Comment: I just tried deploying to my Lumia 950XL and it worked.  But strangely it still doesn't work on windows 10 desktop.

Comment: got it working after a reboot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi if you get Allowed so it should works fine but double check some points I mention below : 
1-Make sure your background Task project be a Windows Runtime Component Project not a class library or others .

2-Make sure your background task project now is a reference in the project you want to call it .

3-Make sure you define your background task , it's entry point and it's type in AppxManifest

4-If all of the things I mentioned were OK so in your C# code call your Background task entry point in this way , some times it will solve your problem .

```
BackgroundTaskBuilder build = new BackgroundTaskBuilder();
build.TaskEntryPoint = typeof(BGTaskRTComponentProj.BGTaskClass).FullName;
```

Comment: Tried all that still doesn't work on the desktop but worked on mobile phone (Lumia 950XL).

Comment: So please send a partial code or share your source if your project is open source to see what's going wrong . 
Also I suggest you put a break point at Run method of background task project and make visual studio don't show any warning pop up to you

Comment: Finally got it working on mobile and desktop.  Should have known for any windows thing...reboot to the rescue!  Yep, no change to the program and reboot works!